# WIX onPaymentUpdate( ) get shipment detail

Tags: javascript, api, payment, velo

I have got to integrate my WIX ecommerce shop with the warehouse API for sending them all the order detail. My problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the "Buyer Info" (shipping address, name, surname email address, quantity, price, item sku....) from the WIX form, once that the payment has been confirmed, in order to send this detail to the warehouse.
I am using the "Wix Payments" provider and PayPal

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned "**Wix ecommerce shop**" and "**Buyer Info**" which are linked to Wix Stores so I'm assuming you have Wix Stores installed on your site.

You should use the [onNewOrder](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-stores-backend/events/onneworder) event from the Wix Stores Backend API. Send it to your Warehouse API using POST request with the details in the POST body.

[onPaymentUpdate()](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-pay-backend/events/onpaymentupdate) is related to the [Wix Pay API](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-pay/introduction) which is not related to Wix Stores.

Comment: You are right but the onNewOrder event return an Object which miss the SKU and other item details. onOrderPaid seems to be more complete but thanks anyway!

Comment: You can use the orderId from the NewOrderEvent that is passed to the onNewOrder function to get the rest of the order info from the Stores/Orders collection.